# Why would the Doctor get his tie?

Tags: doctor-who

In the first episode with Martha Jones (S3:E1), in the first few scenes of the show, he takes off his tie and drops it, completely unknowing of his future to return and retrieve it.

Later, to show Martha he can travel in time, he goes back and picks the tie of the floor. Unless we're just having to accept that tie stayed completely dry all day and in that position, we can assume that The Doctor basically did something he was against -- visit his own timeline -- seconds within the drop, to pick it up and return. This is also risking being seen, and Time Lord would recognise the Tardis sounding.

Regardless of the state of that tie (holding the suspension of disbelief), that was an incredibly risky move. While it holds up to the feel of Tennant's magical, quick, exciting Doctor, it's not very Doctor-like.

Why would a time-lord, who consistently travels around time constantly writing parts in his image (or stopping others from ruining that image), go back on his own time-line, just to return and show Martha? It seems like insanity.

Comment: He says it himself: "*Crossing into established events is strictly forbidden. Except for cheap tricks*"

Comment: @BMWurm My point was that it isn't a *cheap* trick.

Comment: True, it's the Doctor trolling Martha... but it might actually be more the writer trolling the viewers. You are right, it's risky and irresponsible, but it probably gets a laugh out of at least part of the audience and makes it a memorable scene. I haven't seen it in close to a decade and still remembered the quote.

Comment: Are you *sure* he drops the tie? As in on the floor?  I always thought he only takes it off in front of her ....

Comment: @BMWurm - He puts it in his pocket

Comment: @Valorum He lowers his hand below frame... i assumed he put it in his coat... which is what makes the sound as if he dumped a piece of cloth on the floor... ...  Yeah... thought so too... but it is an ambiguous scene

Comment: As for the Doctor not willing to visit his own timeline, there are episodes [with multiple Doctors in them](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_multi-Doctor_stories). The rule of not encountering yourself or your own timeline gets broken, a lot.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The entire point of the scene is that the Doctor traveled backwards in time, created a memorable event and then immediately left.

The Doctor you see accosting Martha at the start of the show isn't a Doctor from a *different* timeline, he's the same Doctor you see at the end of the episode, just moving backwards along Martha's timeline.

[image]

Now, obviously there's a slight risk that he'll bump into himself (and cause a rupture in space and time, destroying the universe), but I'm guessing when you spend as much time in 20th/21st Century London as the Doctor does, he's gotten used to just pretending that he doesn't see himself.

---

As to the tie, you can see him pocket it as he walks away.

[image]

Comment: Cracking diagram +1 for the hand-drawn elements

Comment: @Longshanks - I did think twice before posting the diagrams. I've realised that often people can become jealous of my talent.

Comment: Also, he himself in the past was already a patient in the hospital and usually travels to a specific moment in time once, so the risk of he meeting himself was pretty low.